# Foreach duplicating results (2 databases) (is there a way to exclude repeats?)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I am working in WordPress, MySQL and PHP. As soon as an item is added to the "read" table, the "items" table data duplicates (each time I add more than one item to checked, the items duplicate. So if there are 4 items in read -- it multiplies). I can't seem to work out why it's doing this. My code and database info is below:

`$GLOBALS['a']` is a variable that a user can put into a shortcode that sorts the items by the ID of the group (list) it's within.

**Code**

```
<div class="user-read">
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$q2_read = $wpdb->prefix.'plugin_read';
$q2_item = $wpdb->prefix.'plugin_items';

$q2_results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $q2_item.id, $q2_item.listID, $q2_item.itemDESC, $q2_item.creator, $q2_item.title, $q2_read.userID, $q2_read.itemID, $q2_read.list FROM $q2_item INNER JOIN $q2_read ON $q2_item.id != $q2_read.itemID");

$new_array = array_filter(
    $q2_results, 
    function($v) { return $v->listID == "'" + $GLOBALS['a'] + "'"; }
);

?>
 <?php foreach($new_array as $i ) {
        $bookTITLE = $i->title;
        $groupID = $i->listID;
        $groupCREATOR = $i->creator;
        $bookDESC = $i->itemDESC;
        $bookID = $i->id;
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        ?>
        <?php if($groupCREATOR == ''.$current_user->ID.''|| $groupCREATOR == 'administrator') { ?>
        <div class="user-wrap">
            <div class="inner-wrap">
                <div><span class="check"><form><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $bookID;?>"></form></span></div>
                <div>
                    <b><?php echo $bookTITLE; ?></b><br>
                    <?php echo $bookDESC ; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <?php } else {
        }; ?>
<?php }; ?>
```

`plugin_read` table:

| id | userID | itemID | list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 1 |

`plugin_items` table:

| id | title | itemDESC | creator | listID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | - | - | administrator | 2 |
| 3 | - | - | administrator | 1 |
| 4 | - | - | administrator | 1 |
| 5 | - | - | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | - | - | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | - | - | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | - | - | 1 | 1 |

Maybe there is a better way to do this and I'm just over complicating things?

Comment: Your code references `INNER JOIN $q2_checked` but there is no `$q2_checked` variable  mentioned in the code you provided.

Comment: @kmoser So sorry! I fixed that, it was supposed to be $q2_read, but still repeating the values in the foreach sadly :(

Comment: Do the rows in the database table repeat or do they repeat just in the foreach loop?

Comment: @nice_dev Hi Thank you for commenting! When I print the array from $new_array they are also repeating there, do you think the problem lies in my database SELECT query? I've been staring at this code and trying to debug it for the past 5 hours and I cannot figure out where it went wrong.

Comment: @nice_dev Tested out printing the array from $q2_results as well in case the filter was the issue, but they are also still duplicating there. It must be the select query, I just have no idea what could be causing it to repeat there, I'm still new to a lot of SQL

Comment: @CodeChic Ok, check your insert query once again and look for any hidden database triggers.

Comment: This `"'" + $GLOBALS['a'] + "'"`, is not how you concatenate strings in PHP.

Comment: Hi @ArleighHix ! That is a wordpress attribute I am using and that was the only way to make it global in all the code I had been using for the shortcode, if you know a better way I would appreciate any insight (I know there are better ways to achieve what I am doing, this whole thing is a bit of a mess but I'm not sure other solutions) Thank you!  I did do a hardcoded value to see if it was causing the repeating/duplicating but sadly the filter wasn't :( Also thank you for commenting!

Comment: @nice_dev I feel like the error happens because of the JOIN, but I can't pin point the issue with it exactly. Because it does join the two tables, perhaps the id's or something get mixed up somewhere. Could that cause it? I'm fairly new to sql queries so I could be completely wrong with my guess here. Thank you for replying!

Comment: @CodeChic Bingo! Yes, the `ON $q2_item.id != $q2_read.itemID` makes a particular row from `$q2_item` have several pairs of matches with `$q2_read`. Is this how the join is intended to be or should it be `ON $q2_item.id = $q2_read.itemID`?

Comment: @nice_dev It was intended to filter them out, to take the id from item and compare it to the itemID in read then not include the items that have the corresponding id in read.

Comment: @nice_dev If I do the `ON $q2_item.id = $q2_read.itemID` it shows the ones that have been checked off, but what I'm wanting it to do is filter the ones out that have been checked off (it does) but it then repeats everything which is not what it should do >.< Thank you for taking the time to help with this!

Comment: `"'" . $GLOBALS['a'] . "'"`

Comment: @ArleighHix Thank you so much! I think I've been doing javascript for too long, which was what the + were about. I truly appreciate you helping me with that part!

Comment: @CodeChic _then not include the items that have the corresponding id in read._ In this case you can simply use a NOT IN instead of a join.

Comment: @nice_dev I think though because I am comparing that in that way, it's causing it to repeat. Because if I have 2 items in `read` it does the initial print + 1 repeat. But if I have 3 in there, it does the initial print + 2 repeats. If I have 4, it does the initial print, then 3 repeats. I just am not sure why it's repeating every item depending on how many are in the `read` table

Comment: @nice_dev I feel awful asking, but where at in the query would that go? Thank you so much!!

Comment: @nice_dev If you want you can make that an answer so that if it works, I'll mark it as the answer, thank you again for taking time out of your day to help, I really truly appreciate it!

Comment: @CodeChic SO as a platform is devs for devs. I  do acknowledge your appreciation and return the same back to you but you don't have to be too grateful(lol!) . So the overall question is to fetch rows from `items` that don't exist in `read`, correct?

Comment: @nice_dev I understand! Thank you! And yes, that is exactly what I am trying to accomplish, to fetch rows from `items` that do not exist in `read`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch rows from `items` that don't exist in `read`, you can use a simply *NOT IN* to fetch only those rows which don't exist in `read` as below:

```
<?php

$q2_results = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT * 
  FROM $q2_item
  where $q2_item.id NOT IN (select itemID from $q2_read)
");
```